# Trying to make hmac-sha256 work with Powershell for Canvas API

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell, canvas

I was appointed the task of making a process in which a PowerShell script needs to make a call to Canvas servers in order to get data out of it for other uses that are outside the scope of this question.

The first thing I did was research how the Canvas API actually works. I eventually found this [post](https://community.canvaslms.com/docs/DOC-5553) holds everything I think I should know about the API. The API requires an HMAC SHA 256 hash.

I have decided to reverse engineer his the writer's code that makes the hash in order to make the same script in PowerShell.

Here is my slightly edited code (node.js)

```
var crypto = require('crypto')  
var url = require('url')  
var HMAC_ALG = 'sha256'  
var apiAuth = module.exports = {  
  buildMessage: function(secret, timestamp, uri) {  
    var urlInfo = url.parse(uri, false);  
    var query = urlInfo.query ? urlInfo.query.split('&').sort().join('&') : '';  
    var parts = [ 'GET', urlInfo.host, '', '', urlInfo.pathname, query, timestamp, secret ]  
    console.log(parts);
    return parts.join('\n');  

  },  
  buildHmacSig: function(secret, timestamp, reqOpts,message) {  
    //var message = apiAuth.buildMessage(secret, timestamp, reqOpts);        
    var hmac = crypto.createHmac(HMAC_ALG, new Buffer(secret))  
    hmac.update(message)
    Console.log(message);
    return hmac.digest('base64')  
  }  
}
```

Here are the parameters that I put in the node js application

```
var canvas = require('[filepath]/new_canvas');
var secret = 'mycrazysecret';
var today = new Date();
var timestamp= today.toUTCString();
var regOpts = 'mycrazymessage';
var message = canvas.buildMessage(secret, timestamp, regOpts)
var hmac = canvas.buildHmacSig(secret, timestamp, regOpts,message);
```

the final code it this
'Oexq8/ulAGxSIQXGDVqoXyqk5x+n9cMrc3avcTW9aZk='

Here is my PowerShell file:

```
function buffer 
{
   param ($string)
   $c=@()

   Foreach ($element in $string.toCharArray()) {$c+= [System.Convert]::ToSByte($element)}

   return $c
}

$message = 'GET\n\n\n\nmycrazymessage\n\nFri, 18 Nov 2016 15:29:52 GMT\nmycrazysecret'
$secret = 'mycrazysecret'
$hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha.key = buffer -string $secret
$signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($message))
$signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)

echo $signature
```

The final result is 'pF92zam81wclnnb8csDsscsSYNQ7it9qLrcJkRTi5rM='

I do not know getting the to produce the same results is even possible, but the question I am asking why aren't they producing to different results? (the keys are the same as well)

Comment: In the node js sample the timestamp is a variable, in the PowerShell file it's a string.  Could this impact the resulting hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerShell, the default escape sequence uses backticks `` ` `` rather than backslash `\`.

In order for the parser to recognize the escape sequence as not just a backtick character literal and the letter `n`, use an expandable string (`"` instead of `'`):

```
$message = "GET`n`n`n`nmycrazymessage`n`nFri, 18 Nov 2016 15:29:52 GMT`nmycrazysecret"
```

Other than that, your HMAC signature procedure is correct (it correctly outputs `Oexq8/ulAGxSIQXGDVqoXyqk5x+n9cMrc3avcTW9aZk=` after changing the `$message` value)